# Public office draft

Tags: story-identification, politics

I remember a story where public offices were filled not by candidates running, but by selection, similar to jury duty.  Does this ring any bells?

Comment: Is there any science fiction or fantasy elements to this story? Do you remember when it might have been written?

Comment: Why do suspect this story was science fiction or fantasy? When did you see it? What format was it in? We need way more information than this.

Comment: It does ring a bell of a story which was, I think, called "Franchise", where one single voter was selected and questioned, which selected the president.

Comment: This sort of system is called [*sortition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortition), and it was already in use in ancient Athens.

Comment: I remember a story similar to that where they would chose a successful business man and appoint him president, liquidate all his assets, and after his term was over he would receive assets based on how well things went during his term.   As I recall it was by a science fiction author, but can't recall which one at the momment

Comment: I recall a short story in one of Robert Sheckley's books where they appoint a new president by inviting applicants, ruling out those who apply, on the basis that anyone who wants to be president is unsuitable and then appointing someone else at random, whether the appointee likes it or not.

Comment: There's a short story by Christopher Anvil, "The Troublemaker" (found in Interstellar Patrol II), where the public offices, of which we see the king, are chosen by selection (and that is the word used).  In the story, anyone who qualifies lines up, there's a speech about responsibility, and whoever steps forward is selected.  The point of the story includes the safeguards that allows such a system to work, and the office to be considered a responsibility that people would like out of, rather than a privilege.

Comment: @MartynA, do you remember where this story was?

Comment: @JackBNimble, it was in a science fiction collection, I believe, but that's about it.  It wasn't Asimov's "Franchise".

Comment: "Where" as in which book?  I'm afraid not, but there's a bibliography of his stuff here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sheckley_short_stories_bibliography

Answer (score 4):

There is a short story by Asimov, called ["Franchise"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchise_%28short_story%29).

But it's the *voter*, not the candidates, that is drafted. Since computers have become better at predicting the outcome of elections, only a single voter is drafted.

> The man presented credentials, stepped into the house, closed the door behind him and said ritualistically, "Mr. Norman Muller, it is necessary for me to inform you on the behalf of the President of the United States that you have been chosen to represent the American electorate on Tuesday, November 4, 2008."

He is then interviewed by the computer, MultiVac, about all kinds of seemingly unrelated issues.

> "Now let me explain, Mr. Muller," Paulson went on. "Multivac already has most of the information it needs to decide all the elections, national, state and local. It needs only to check certain imponderable attitudes of mind and it will use you for that. We can't predict what questions it will ask, but they may not make much sense to you, or even to us. It may ask you how you feel about garbage disposal in your town; whether you favor central incinerators. It might ask you whether you have a doctor of your own or whether you make use of National Medicine, Inc. Do you understand?"

From this, the computer decides the outcome of the election.

> In this imperfect world, the sovereign citizens of the first and greatest Electronic Democracy had, through Norman Muller (through *him*!) exercised once again its free, untrammeled franchise.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the novel version of [Clarke's ***The Songs of Distant Earth***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Songs_of_Distant_Earth)? My recollection is that public officials were chosen at random; as long as they weren't criminals or insane, they were compelled to serve a term in whatever job they had been selected for.