# Business man made leader

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story in where the political system they used is that they would select a successful business man, liquidate all of his assets (it becomes state money) and at the end of their term they would be given back assets in proportion to how well they did during their term.

I read this story before 2000 and it was in English, as I recall it was in a collection of short stories by that author (but my memory could be playing tricks).  But it is probably even older than that.

Comment: When they sold off all the rich man's assets did it play hell with the markets?

Comment: Sounds familiar, but just the concept, not the story. Has this been asked before?

Comment: @SQB If you can find a duplicate, that's fine with me ;-)   I have mentioned it in a comment here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116695/public-office-draft#comment284839_116695

Comment: The up vote on that comment is mine; that's likely to be where I remember it from.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting concept, but I'm not sure if it's on-topic for this site. Unless it's set in a dystopian future or something.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Of course it's on topic for this site. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Because while set in an alternate, fictional universe, it doesn't display any tropes of Science-Fiction or Fantasy. Is _any_ fiction deemed on-topic? Can I go around asking questions about books written by E.L James or John Steinbeck? Because they don't seem like they'd be a good fit for this SE.

Answer (score 6):

While it is not a short story the Tamuli series by David Eddings has a character detailing a political system like this one

There was no real story though simply a character detailing how the political system of their home country works (and slightly bragging that their government manages to turn a profit)

Comment: As I have read this series, this could well be it, and I just miss-remembered it being a short story.